# UWP CustomRenderer for Checkbox: Pointer over Checkbox changes style?

Tags: c#, checkbox, xamarin.forms, custom-controls

I'm working with Xamarin.Forms and I made a CustomRenderer for Checkbox in UWP. When I set all the Checkboxes of my items in the `ListView` to `true` by clicking the button "Alle", the Checkboxes are displayed correctly with the check inside the box:

[image]

However, if I hover my mouse over the Checkboxes, they immediately change their appearence (the check disappears but it's still selected). In the following screenshot, I moved my cursor over the 3rd - 7th Checkboxes:

[image]

This is my overridden `OnElementChanged` method in the CustomRenderer:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<EvaCheckbox> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);
    var model = e.NewElement;
    if (model == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    nativeCheckbox = new CheckBox();
    CheckboxPropertyChanged(model, null);
    model.PropertyChanged += OnElementPropertyChanged;

    nativeCheckbox.Checked += (object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs eargs) =>
    {
        model.IsChecked = (bool)nativeCheckbox.IsChecked;
    };

    nativeCheckbox.Unchecked += (object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs eargs) =>
    {
        model.IsChecked = (bool)nativeCheckbox.IsChecked;
    };

    SetNativeControl(nativeCheckbox);
}
```

I tried to override the `PointerEntered` event of `nativeCheckbox`. It works, for example if I set the model.IsChecked to true on this event, it will be set to true:

```
nativeCheckbox.PointerEntered += (s, args) =>
{
    model.IsChecked = true;
};
```

But I don't know how to (if even at this place) prevent the checkbox from changing it's appearance when moving the cursor above the Checkbox. Just leaving the triggered event with empty code like this won't change anything about the described behaviour:

```
nativeCheckbox.PointerEntered += (s, args) => { };
```

How can I prevent the Checkbox from changing it's appearance when I move my cursor over it?

### Update:

I've created a sample project for this issue. You can find the repository here: https://github.com/Zure1/CustomCheckbox

It has the exact same described behavior. In the following screenshot I pressed the button "All" on the bottom of the screen and then the checkboxes look like correct with a check inside of them:

[image]

After moving the mouse cursor over the bottom 3 checkboxes, their change their appearance:

[image]

Information: I'm debugging on my desktop (Windows 10). I don't know if this issue exists on WinPhone. Just in case you're wondering why my checkboxes are red: My system color in Windows is red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tricky one as I have been struggling with this issue for a while, I'll try my best to answer this.

TL;DR: It's caused by ViewCell.

The issue comes down to Xamarin Forms ListView and ViewCell.

I haven't been able to track down the cause yet for many months and the way I get around this issue is by refreshing the ListView every time a change happens forcing a redraw of the entire ListView which can really impact performance.

My educated guess on what the cause could be is the rendering code for the ViewCell is missing something.

As for your particular issue, I have created a CheckBoxCell which you can use to display a list of checkboxes with a title. [I forked your project and made the changes.](https://github.com/charsleysa/CustomCheckbox/tree/charsleysa-patch-1)

This will display something similar to what you are trying to achieve and doesn't have rendering issues so will be a good starting point. You are able to customize this to display images and the like but you'll have to do that in the platform-specific layout code.

Please note that I have only created the code for UWP and that should be enough to get you going for the other platforms.

I hope this helps somewhat.

[image: CheckBoxCell list]